# How to externally populate play! model

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

What would be the best idea to fill the play! models with data from an external source?

So far my application is small enough, that simply writing a Scala app doing JDBC inserts wouldn't be problem at all, but I really hate this idea.

Preferably I'd love to be able to use play! models from a standalone shell scala app, but so far I wasn't able to figure out how to do it. is really creating a view and calling it with curl (for example) the only chance to do it?

Thanks,
Michal

Comment: Why a view? A Json api should be good enough?

Comment: Yeah, correct - Json is an option. Don't know why I haven't thought about it earlier. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Json api should be good enough?

Comment: Json api is good enough. Last night I have coded the model population code wiht it, and restricted the URL path leading to it on the server so it's available only locally. Thanks for tip.